# Excel Data Entry made faster with Macro?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am currently trying write a macro in excel to help shorten the time that this will take.  I have water sample data for 10 different manholes and each were sampled quarterly since 1994. Because of this, I have a total of 75 dates that I need to input per manhole for this spreadsheet. Each of these dates has 97 rows of information that is input into this sheet and then a space before going to the next date.  My ultimate question is, how can I take the dates shown from the first image and copy the first one 97 times, then second 97 times without redundantly doing so.  Example is the image attached.[image]

Comment: To answer the ultimate question, this can be done through VBA or a rather simple formula.

Comment: Is this picture of your input or of your expected output?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 expected output. So from Jan_02 it goes to Apr_02 then Jul_02 then Oct_02.  Then it will go back to Jan_03 and so on. Each of the sampling dates is posted 97 times.

Comment: you dont really need a macro. You can use the actual dates, especially since you have data for each quarter so you will always move 3 months. Write the the starting date 97 times with a blank cell above it and then use for example =IF(A1="";"";EDATE(A1;3)) just below the last cell with the date and copy down to line 8000. finished. Now you can just concatenate the year, month & day of the date together with your MW03 or anything else you want there.

Answer (score 1):

In column A have an integer sequence, starting at 0 and going up. In column B, do integer division on column A (QUOTIENT). You'll integer divide by the number of times you want things repeated (97). Then in column C, use VLOOKUP, taking the value from column B as the index into your lookup table, to "copy" the values for dates.

If you have the same measurements for each date, you can use a new column that uses MOD on column A, then use that as the index for a second VLOOKUP into your measurements lookup table.